# Stored procedure disconnecting codeigniter from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Hello This is a conceptual question mostly.

I have written a stored procedure in mysql that works correctly and returns the result I am expecting. I can then call that SP from a codeiigniter library I wrote. It gives the correct result to the server and then the correct data can be displayed to the client. However, if I attempt to hit the back button or refresh the page, I receive the following error:

```
    A Database Error Occurred
    Unable to select the specified database: stage
    Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\Web\system\database\DB_driver.php
    Line Number: 140
```

I'm not sure where the problem is originating. I'm worried that it is a configuration issue, or something like that. I'm using codeigniter V 2.0.1. Does anyone have any similar experiences with SPs in CI? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was related to the problem listed here:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/71141/

This ended up being a case where xampp made it so that these errors would not resolve as normal, leading me to believe that this was some other issue. By setting my database config file to use mysqli and by building a hook into the core to modify the way codeigniter handles queries returned from mysqli stored procedures everything was able to work together. Thank you for your help everyone, it helped me find the true source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The connection to the database might be closed by that time. Check your `config/database.php` and see if changing persistent connect to `TRUE` changes anything:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you, but pconnect is already TRUE. I think I might have figured it out. For codeigniter, a stored procedure might require a db name in its create line i.e. db_name.sp_name. However, this might not fix the problem entirely, so if anyone has more suggestions, please.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instruction of codeigniter

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to reconnect to the database

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

change it to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: How is the issue solved with your change? I understand why you want the OP to use mysqli instead of mysql but the truth is this question is 3 years old and your answer doesn't solve the OP's issue.